# Joomla 3 не запускается js под определенным пользователем

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

Всем привет, столкнулся первый раз с таким явлением. Когда определенный пользователь проходит авторизацию, js скрипты перестают работать, в чем может бить причина? У всех остальных все нормально только у него одного косяки, подскажите еде искать решение?

Comment: Вообщем у супер админа скрипты работают а у обычных пользователях нет, не работает только на одной страницы.